# How to display a version # in a customUI ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I have a Excel VBA project where I expect to issue updates. It has a custom UI ribbon. For support purposes (screen captures), I want to display the app's version number in the ribbon, which would be read from a hidden sheet. I was hoping to do this with just a label control. But it does not appear that a label control has a callback. I thought I would try it with an `Edit Box` without an `on_change` capability. Unless I am using it wrong, `InvalidateControl` still allows me to type into the `Edit Box`.

```vb
Sub GetVersion(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef sVversion)
    sVversion = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
    myRibbon.InvalidateControl "GetVersion"
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Other ideas I have considered would be a button control that displays the version in a `MsgBox` or `UserForm`, or a button with no functionality and just displays a `SuperTip`.

Comment: Label control do have `getLabel` if i remember correctly... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/965555a2-93db-48a6-a6bf-5dd08a13f6bb

Comment: I presume that by "supertip" you meant "tool tip". If you meant something different, please [edit] to change it back and explain what a "supertip" is.

Comment: @FreeMan `getSupertip` is a property of ribbon controls. It effectively sets a tooltip for the control.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, I didn't know that. I've not messed with custom ribbons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [labelControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#labelcontrol) provides the following callbacks and attributes:

```
enabled, getEnabled, getLabel, getScreentip, getShowLabel, getSupertip, getVisible, id, idMso, idQ, insertAfterMso, insertAfterQ, insertBeforeMso, insertBeforeQ, label, screentip, showLabel, supertip, tag, visible
```

The `getLabel` callback gets the label for a control and has the following signature:

```
C#: string GetLabel(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetLabel(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)

C++: HRESULT GetLabel([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] BSTR *pbstrLabel)

Visual Basic: Function GetLabel(control As IRibbonControl) As String
```

It seems you have just chosen a wrong signature and the Office runtime can't locate the callback specified in the ribbon XML.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: You are correct in your assumption. I was not had the correct signature. I was using Office RibbonX Editor, and it did not create a callback.  But I somehow missed that  there was a `getLabel` callback. And indeed that does exactly what I wanted it to. And thanks for the links.  I like that info better than MS documentation site.